# How to know using Django if server is secure (uses https)

Tags: python, django, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I work on a Django based app, and I want to know if there's a way to know if my server uses http connections or https.

I know that using

```
import socket
if socket.gethostname().startswith('****'):
```

I can get the hostname, is it possible to do something like that so I can get to know if the hosting uses a ssl certificate?

**PD:** I'm a rookie here, so I'm asking to see if it's possible and, if it is, how should I do it.
Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

it's completely possible:

```
def some_request_function(request):
    if request.is_secure():
        #You are safe!
    else:
        #You are NOT safe!
```

More details:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.is_secure

Comment: Thanks, How would it be in settings.py?

Answer (score 4):

There simply is an [`is_secure()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.is_secure) method on the request object, returning True if the connection is secure.

Depending on your specific server configuration you may also need to set  [`SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#secure-proxy-ssl-header) in your settings.

Comment: This seems more like what I'm looking for. How would it be in settings.py?

Comment: What server do you use (nginx, apache)?

Comment: nginx. Same question here (about settings.py)

Comment: @chefarov `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')`. Also make sure you've got `proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Protocol  $scheme;` in you nginx configuration.

Answer (score 3):

django requests (`HttpRequest`) have `is_secure` method:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.is_secure

Comment: Just a question. How would it be in settings.py?

Comment: it's not. By default it checks the server enviorn (`os.environ`) to see if 'https' is the scheme https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/request.py#L137, It looks like you can define what a secure header is by defining SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER in your settings though. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#secure-proxy-ssl-header