# DjangoCMS: disable login via http, force https

Tags: django, https, django-cms

Our DjangoCMS site is accessible via http and https.

Anonymous usage via http is ok. But I want to disable logins via http.

Is there a way to force the usage of https as soon as the user wants to login?

Even the login-page (with username and password fields) should not be available via http.

Background: I don't want the password to go over the wire unencrypted.

Update: The site gets hosted on an apache web server.

Comment: Why not just redirect all traffic to https?

Comment: Well, it's one part the login page being served as HTTPS, but what is with cookies after the user is authenticated? IMHO you should only serve HTTPS and not only if a user wants to login.

Comment: @user1 I have not thought about this detail up to now.

Comment: Do you know what webserver is used to deploy your DjangoCMS site? Usually this is Apache, Nginx, IIS, or something similar. You probably want to address this at the webserver level, not Django.

Comment: @sytech I updated the question: The site gets hosted on an apache web server.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As I already mentioned it in the comments I strongly suggest you to **NOT** only serve the login page via `https`.

Doing so just hides the fact that for example session information and authentication data is still transfered on the other requests unencrypted via `http`. Your site will not be secure at all.

You're just pseudo-securing stuff so it's fancy to somebodys eye. It's just like using the password `12345`.

So please serve your website over `https` to the user. A small guide, for nginx or apache2, on how to redirect your traffic from `http` to `https` can be found here:

- [Redirecting to SSL using nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18523180/redirecting-to-ssl-using-nginx)
- [Force redirect to SSL for all pages apart from one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724968/force-redirect-to-ssl-for-all-pages-apart-from-one)

Comment: Your answer does not match my question :-) But: Yes, you are right. It is time to server everything via https. I guess I will use https://letsencrypt.org/

Comment: @Stocklappen, when you suggest *not* only serve the logging page via https, does it mean that you recommend serving the login page via http too?
I don't understand how serving only https login pages can hide information being sent unencrypted. Shouldn't that  be impossible if all traffic is redirected to port 443 and port 80 is closed?

Comment: I suggest to use https for everything. Login-page only via https and then the rest via http is nuts because of session data being transmitted unencrypted.

Answer (score 4):

As you've accepted in the comments, pushing all traffic to HTTPS is the best solution these days. If you only authenticate via SSL, you'll need to consider encryption/security in everything you write moving forward rather than it just being the default.

So in your server config, force all traffic to port 443. Assuming you're using apache you'd do this;

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName www.example.com
     Redirect / https://www.example.com/
 </VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost *:443>
     ServerName www.example.com
     # ... SSL configuration goes here
 </VirtualHost>
```

Then in your Django settings turn on secure cookies;

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

As a side note, Django has a setting to redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS which is `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT`, but if you're doing this at the apache/nginx level you don't need to worry. For some further reading on SSL/HTTPS have a look here; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/security/#ssl-https

Answer (score 3):

Django request has a is_secure()

You can check it in the view and redirect if not is secure:

```
if not request.is_secure():
    return redirect("https://www.yourdomain.com/login")
```

Comment: Above code snippet looks good. But where should I place these two lines?

Comment: In the view you want to force the https. For instance the login view. If is a Generic view you can use the get_context_data, or post your login view and i can suggest you where.

Answer (score 3):

*@user1 has the logic right and you should serve your site through https in order to have it safe.*
But in order to answer your exact question:

As shown here: [How to know using Django if server is secure (uses https)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21632587/how-to-know-using-django-if-server-is-secure-uses-https?answertab=votes#tab-top) and as @Zartch mentions in his answer, you should use the [`is_secure()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.is_secure) HTTPRequest method to check if your request is coming through https.

- In order to use `is_secure()` you need to check an incoming request
  to your views:

  ```
  def my_login_view(request):
      if request.is_secure():
          Do loggin
      else:
          Don't login
  ```
- Now you can protect your other views with the [`login_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required) decorator:

  ```
  @login_required(login_url='/your/login/url')
  def protected_view(request):
      ...
  ```

---

*Personal suggestion:* I use [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) extensively and I would suggest it, in your case, because it has an [`isAuthenticatedOrReadOnly`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#isauthenticatedorreadonly) permission class which you will like:

```
class MyLoginView(ObtainAuthToken):
    """
    Login view for token-based authentication
    """
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.is_secure():
            super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            Probably some redirect goes here...
```

Then in any other view or class-based view:

```
class MyOtherView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
    ...
```

The above will ensure that your users can login only through https and if they are not logged in they will only see a read-only view.

Give it a try if you like.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't accept an answer yet, so I thought, that the answers might not match your question well enough.

> Anonymous usage via http is ok. But I want to disable logins via http.

As I understand, you have the following use case:

*Some person visits your website as anonymous user, the used protocol is http.
This person opens the login form and logs in, the form is sent through https.
The logged in user continues browsing your website through https.*

If the login form is routed to the secure version your user will continue browsing your website in https mode (as long as all other links are agnostic to the used protocol).

`<form action="https://your.domain/path/to/login/" method="post">`

If the application you're using to authenticate users is sanely written, you can configure your [`settings.LOGIN_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#login-url), else you'll probably need to do it in the template form.

I recommend allowing session cookies to be sent only through https, using [`settings.SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#session-cookie-secure).
With this setting, the user will still be able to make http requests, but the session cookie will not be sent (and the user will be treated as an anonymous user).

Please, make sure that your login view accepts only secure post requests (or else the user may send the password through non https protocol).
This can be achieved either in the Django code (like John Moutafis suggests with his `MyLoginView`) or at production server level by rejecting non https post requests for the login URL.

--

Could you provide access to the repository with the code?

Comment: The `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE` only flags the cookie as `secure`. This does not force delivery via https at all. If you set the flag and serve your site via http you'll instead get `CSRF` errors due to this setting.

Comment: Hi user1! I might need to reword the sentence. What I try to say is that the cookie is only sent, if the connection is secure. You can still make an http request, but the cookie will not be sent in that case (and therefore no session).

Answer (score 0):

You may use one or a combination of:

- **htaccess file**, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398951/force-ssl-https-using-htaccess-and-mod-rewrite)
- **webserver level**, depend of server type: Apache, Nginx, IIS ?...
- **django server level**, take a look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/security), and [host header validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/security/#host-header-validation) or [SSL/HTTPS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/security/#ssl-https)